# Adding a custom class to a Qt project

Tags: c++, qt

I've been coding a physics simulation that holds in a custom class and I'm know trying to code a GUI with Qt 4.8 for it.

It seems to me that the right to do that is to add one instance of my class as a member of my MainWindow object in Qt.

My homecooked class works finely on its side but I'm having trouble in adding it to the Qt project. I tried using the usual
   #include "my_custom_class.h" (everything is defined in this header, I usually don't split it in a cpp file)

to my mainwindow.h file and, when compiling I get for every member of my first class an error message : multiple definition of my_custom_class::member1() , etc...

I also tried the:

class my_custom_class;

but it doesn't work either, and I'm not comfortable with that as I don't really understand what it really does.

Comment: can you provide us the actual error message? are you adding your cpp file to the qt project file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I usually don't split it in a cpp file

C and C++ have headers (.h) and implmentation (.c / .cpp) files for a reason. Without seeing the code, I'd say you're making it difficult for yourself by not using an implementation file too.

Again, without you showing your code, it's difficult to exactly identify the problem, but my guess is that you're lacking a header guard.

When you call #include for your header, the compiler adds the contents of that file for building. If multiple files call the same #include, either directly, or indirectly by calling a file that includes your header file, then the same symbols get added for compilation, causing errors of 'multiple definition for....'

What you can do is add a header guard in your header file, like this: -

```
#ifndef _MYCLASS_H_
#define _MYCLASS_H_

//... add your class here

#endif
```

The first time your header is included, it will add the symbols and define _MYCLASS_H_. Any subsequent calls to include your header will see that the _MY_CLASS_H_ is already defined and won't add the symbols again.

You should do this for all header files. I also recommend you define the class in the header and create a separate implementation file to go with it. If anything, it will speed up compilation time.

Comment: problem if the header is included in multiple source files then the implementations will be in different obj files which will make the linker complain unless all functions in the header are marked `inline`

Comment: @Merlin: I was already using a header guard, I just tried splitting into .h and .cpp and it compiles like a charm. I'm not sure of why but it may because of the way qtcreator passes the headers and dependencies to qmake. Many thanks ;)